# Syncing Core Data: iOS to OSX, vice versa

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, core-data, synchronization

I'm exploring my options for syncing Core Data from iOS apps to OSX, and vice versa. I just watched a presentation on zSync as a possible option, but noticed it's not really updated anymore. Does anyone have any preferred solutions for this?

Thanks,
Zach

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Comment: Could be several MB. But would probably be in segments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sync via iTunes. This is possible since iOS 4.0, I believe.
2. Sync via a server running on the device. You can look [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html) for a simple HTTP server. Other options include WebDAV, FTP, etc.
3. Use cloud sync.

Option 2 and 3 are better if you don't want to sync the entire dataset but only subsets or if you need to do "complex" data syncing (think merging events from a calendar).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you have any info on cloud sync?

Comment: @Zakman411: No. You probably need to create your own API (e.g. via HTTP) and have a custom program run on your server to deal with syncing. Maybe there are prebuilt solutions out there, but I don't know any...